# Create Rows and Columns in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, text-mining

Below is code python code output.I want output in rows and column in dataframe:

```
response = requests.get(source_data) 
   
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

States = soup.find_all('div',class_ = 'card bg-darker p-3 mb-3')

    for item in States :

        state_name = item.find(class_='fw-bold fs-5 mb-2').text

        vaccinated_per = item.find(class_='col-3 text-end fs-5 ff-s text-success').text

        print(state_name,vaccinated_per)
```

**Output:**

> Flanders 80.24%
>
> Wallonia 70.00%
>
> Brussels 56.73%
>
> Ostbelgien 65.11%

Comment: Please give the link address

Comment: https://covid-vaccinatie.be/en

Answer (score 1):

Collect your information in a list of dicts and then simply create a data frame from it:

```
    data = []
    
    for item in States :
    
        data.append({
            'state_name' : item.find(class_='fw-bold fs-5 mb-2').text,
            'vaccinated_per' : item.find(class_='col-3 text-end fs-5 ff-s text-success').text
        })
    
    pd.DataFrame(data)
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

    
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get('https://covid-vaccinatie.be/en', headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

States = soup.find_all('div',class_ = 'card bg-darker p-3 mb-3')

data = []

for item in States :

    data.append({
        'state_name' : item.find(class_='fw-bold fs-5 mb-2').text,
        'vaccinated_per' : item.find(class_='col-3 text-end fs-5 ff-s text-success').text
    })

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

#### Output

```
    state_name  vaccinated_per
0   Flanders    80.24%
1   Wallonia    70.00%
2   Brussels    56.73%
3   Ostbelgien  65.11%
```